# Php IDE: PhpStorm vs free IDEs (Eclipse , NetBeans, etc.)

Tags: php, eclipse, netbeans, ide, phpstorm

I need a PHP IDE with the essential features for a developer:

- validate PHP/JS/HTML5/XML code ( highlight syntax errors )
- run/debug a local site, or a single PHP script
- run/debug a PHPUnit instance ( PhpStorm can do it, you specify which is the xml configuration to use and you launch PHPUnit from there )
- When i run/debug a site or script or PHPUnit, i want to define environment variables which the PHP instance will see. PhpStorm can do it by creating a "Debug configuration" with PHP interpreter options and also environment variables.
- (optional) Debugging PHP remote site

PhpStorm can do all of the above. Is there a free alternative that can do it as well ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options:

1. PhpStorm Early Access Program
2. JetBrains for Students

However, I highly recommend to pay for it, it's worth every cent.

For reference, see:

- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/51185764
- https://www.jetbrains.com/student/

Also, [TANSTAAFL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain't_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch).

Comment: Yes, TANSTAAFL is legit, but hey i'm talking about basic features that i supposed should be free, for example the free version of Visual Studio  already supports them for C#: syntax error highlighting, debugging, etc. About the Early Access version of PhpStorm, is that free or just n-day trial? What about RC or Preview versions? Do they support those feauters as well ?

Comment: The EAP versions have the same features, they are intended to allow users to test upcoming releases, as well as JetBrains to collect feedback on those. If you are a student, you are eligible for receiving free versions, and if you are a maintainer of an open source software project, you might be eligible for receiving free versions as well. Really great software with excellent support. 